# Vue 3 + ResizeObserver (polyfill) not working as expected

Tags: vuejs3, resize-observer

I'm building a component in Vue 3 and using `resize-observer-polyfill` to observe my container size changes.

While converting stuff from prior vue 2 code to vue 3, I ran into an issue where ResizeObserver simply stopped working. It only triggered once, as I called `.observe()` and then stopped triggering.

I have pinpointed the issue to .observe call, which is made from onMounted lifecycle hook, like so:

```
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('a', container.value, getComputedStyle(container.value).position);
  resizeObserver.observe(container.value);  // <-- not working
  nextTick(() => resizeObserver.observe(container.value));  // <-- not working
  setTimeout(() => resizeObserver.observe(container.value), 1);  // <-- working! yay!
});
```

While I'd generally be happy about just leaving it in its newly working state, I can't help but wonder what it the cause of this required delay in `.observe()` call.

I have printed out container's (it's a ref to a div) style and its `position` was `relative`, `display` was `block` even without the delay.

So why do I have to wait to start observing if everything seems to be in place already?

Comment: I can't [repro](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-rgb-lrvgnv?file=/src/App.vue) what you're describing. Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve].

Comment: @tao: Indeed. I tried to modify your example with the component that I think might be causing this (I have a separate component generating style for my mega-component), but codesandbox didn't work for me and I failed.

Comment: Without a way to repro, your question is unanswerable, therefore *off-topic*.

Comment: indeed. Still figuring out how to make a MINIMAL repro sample.